# Intellij 2018 Mac can run tests

Tags: intellij-idea

Recently and after making no changes I cannot run my Java Junit tests anymore.   I am using Intellj Ultimate 2018.1

Not just that I cant run any Java code.

I can't see anything obvious in the idea.log file either.  I even cloned my repo again and imported a new intellij project, but I see the same thing.

This was working fine yesterday and I made no changes.

From idea.log:

```
2019-05-20 16:55:54,951 [ 105928]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2  Build #IU-181.4668.68 

2019-05-20 16:55:54,951 [ 105928]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 

2019-05-20 16:55:54,952 [ 105929]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 

2019-05-20 16:55:54,952 [ 105929]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 

2019-05-20 16:55:54,953 [ 105930]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - OS: Mac OS X 

2019-05-20 16:55:54,953 [ 105930]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - Last Action: RunClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing IntelliJ 2018 and installing IntelliJ 2019. Not the fix I was hoping for but its back working now.